# Hiding Elements for iOS/Android Based on userAgent

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to hide some elements on my Wordpress if a user is on an iOS device.  Likewise, I'm trying to hide some other elements if a user is on Android.  I'm finding that this seems to work for an iPhone user, but not on iPad.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance... my code block is below...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/i)) {
    $('.download').hide();
    $('.rss').hide();
}
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(Android)){
    $('.itunes').hide();
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: try to check seperately like this,   if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || 
 (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)))

Comment: I tried this... for some reason, it doesn't seem to work, either.

Comment: how do you test? with the real device or simulator ?

Comment: I'm testing with a real ipad

Comment: + Tips : you can add class into the <body>'s tag, like `$('body').addClass('hidemyitems');` then code your css like `.hidemyitems .download {display:none;}`

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is embarrassing.  I guess I should pay more attention to parenthesis, huh?  Long day of coding... oh well.

Solution (thanks to Janith above):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/i)) {
    $('.download').hide();
    $('.rss').hide();
};
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)){
    $('.itunes').hide();
};
});
</script>
```